# Animated responsive Svg-Map

Tags: jquery, html, css, svg, responsive

first of all: Merry Christmas!

I'm trying to do a clickable map which is responsive. I'm failing to keep the positions of the svg images stable, see here: http://wp12730465.server-he.de/heim/

I have no idea how to solve this. As you can see, the overlay images jump around and lose their position they're supposed to have when the window is scaled.

Any ideas?
Best,
Anka

Comment: add your html and css codes

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly. I have made a change to `gelaende` div with position of relative.

```
.gelaende {
        position: relative;
        width: 100%;
        float: left;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Merry Christmas too :)
Best way to do that is giving [position : "relative"]to the parent div which in yours is this one(.section):

```
<div class="section">
<div id="responsiveTabs" class="r-tabs">
<ul id="tabs" class="r-tabs-nav">
```

...

& also define [position : "absolute"] for every single image you want to use on the top of that.
Below image is a good example:

```
#heim {
 width: 14vw;
 position: absolute;
 height: auto;
 top: 12vw;
 left: 0;
}
```

As you have noticed top and left positions are needed to be changed for every single image.